# MatSnackBar position error and hide

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am handling errors with MatSnackBar and I have problems with the position in which the dialog is displayed and it is not hidden automatically.

[image]

service.ts

```
facebookLogin() {
const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}

private oAuthLogin(provider) {
return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then((credential) => {
    this.pushUserData(credential.user)
    this.router.navigate(['/userProfile'])
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.handleError(error);

  });
}

private handleError(error: Error) {
  console.error(error);
  this.snackBar.open(error.message, this.action, { duration: 1000 });
}
```

component.ts

```
facebookLogin() {
  this.auth.facebookLogin()
}
```

When I test it from the same component, everything works normal:

```
openSnackBar() {
this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
  duration: 500,
});
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I solved it in the following way, adding ngZone:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor( public snackBar: MatSnackBar, private zone: NgZone )

private handleError(error: Error) {
console.error(error);
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.snackBar.open(error.message, 'CERRAR', {
      duration: 5000,
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Just realized ErrorHandler runs outside angular zone

Comment: Thanks a lot. Already googled around for many minutes, until i found this. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: For me this didn't work, although adding `setTimeout()` fixed the issue. The code: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9875#issuecomment-444218890

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
this.snackBar.open(message, 'Close', { duration: 3500, verticalPosition: 'top', panelClass: 'snack-error'});
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work, this only changes the style of the box but the problem of the position continues

Comment: please, add your HTML file and your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
private handleError(error: Error) {
    console.error(error);
    this.snackBar.open(error.message, this.action,
    { duration: 1000
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center'
    });
}
```

You can check the available configuration options in the documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig)

Comment: These options only affect elements INSIDE the snack, not the position of the snack in the browser.